# Llenar Table con mis datos recibidos en Eclipse WindowsBuilder

Tags: java

Por primera vez estoy tratando de aprender a trabajar con tablas pero, leyendo manuales y videos, no logro entender mucho ya que casi todos estan en ingles.

Mi programa es este, con la tabla añadida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código, solamente tengo esto.

Declaro:

```
private final JTable table;
```

Código de la tabla en sí:

```
table =  new JTable();
        table.setBounds(10, 297, 445, 143);
        contentPane.add(table);
```

De acuerdo a lo que logré entender, hay que crear dos arreglos:

1. `arreglo1 [] = {"#", "origen", "destino", "duracion", "precio"};`
2. `arreglo2 [][] = null;`

Siendo el 1er el título. Hasta aquí no logré entender nada.
Espero puedan ayudarme por favor.
También me interesa tenerle un `Scroll` para poder bajar y subir y ver los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno si tienes razon hay que crear dos arreglos

1) para las cabeceras(o nombre de columna) de tu tabla

```
String[] columnas= {"#", "origen", "destino", "duracion", "precio"};
```

2) para los datos de tu tabla

```
String [][] data = {
                {"1", "Casa", "Trabajo", "20 minutos", "4000"},
                {"2", "Trabajo", "Casa", "30 minutos", "5000"}
};
```

Luego tienes tu tabla

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnas);
JTable tabla = new JTable(model);
```

Para agregar un `scroll` a tu tabla

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
add(scroll);
```

Ahora para agregar distintos valores a tu tabla, como tenemos un `model` que es el orden el cual tu quieres que se muestren los datos

```
Object[] row = {"3", "Casa", "Playa", "50 minutos", "10000"};
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tabla.getModel();

model.addRow(row);
```

**EDIT**

No agregue todo tu codigo porque no tengo las clases ni nada de eso, tampoco pude acomodar visualmente como tu quieres obtener la vista, pero con esto se soluciona el problema. Como la clase `extends` de `JFrame` le damos `add` a los elementos y no es necesario crear un panel.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GUI frame = new GUI();
     frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);
}

public GUI(){
    JTextField txtNumeroOrigen;
    JTextField txtNumeroDestino;
    JTextField txtDuracion;
    JTextField txtPrecioTotal;
    JCheckBox checkboxProvincial;
    JCheckBox checkboxLocal;
    JCheckBox checkboxFranja1;
    JCheckBox checkboxFranja2;
    JCheckBox checkboxFranja3;
    JTextField txtTotalDeLlamadas;
    JTextField txtPrecioActual;
    JTable table;
    setTitle("Call Center");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 471, 480);

    JLabel lblTipo = new JLabel("Tipo:");
    lblTipo.setBounds(16, 30, 46, 14);
    add(lblTipo);

    JLabel lblFraja = new JLabel("Franja:");
    lblFraja.setBounds(125, 30, 46, 14);
    add(lblFraja);

    JLabel lblNmeroOrigen = new JLabel("N\u00FAmero Origen");
    lblNmeroOrigen.setBounds(200, 30, 108, 14);
    add(lblNmeroOrigen);

    JLabel lblNmeroDestino = new JLabel("N\u00FAmero Destino");
    lblNmeroDestino.setBounds(200, 55, 108, 14);
    add(lblNmeroDestino);

    JLabel lblDuracion = new JLabel("Duraci\u00F3n");;
    lblDuracion.setBounds(200, 81, 108, 14);
    add(lblDuracion);

    txtNumeroOrigen = new JTextField();
    txtNumeroOrigen.setBounds(318, 27, 130, 20);
    add(txtNumeroOrigen);
    txtNumeroOrigen.setColumns(10);

    txtNumeroDestino = new JTextField();
    txtNumeroDestino.setBounds(318, 55, 130, 20);
    add(txtNumeroDestino);
    txtNumeroDestino.setColumns(10);

    txtDuracion = new JTextField();
    txtDuracion.setBounds(318, 86, 130, 20);
    add(txtDuracion);
    txtDuracion.setColumns(10);

    Object[][] data = {
            {"1", "Casa", "Trabajo", "20 minutos", "4000"},
            {"2", "Trabajo", "Casa", "30 minutos", "5000"}
     };
     //array de String's con los títulos de las columnas
     String[] columnNames = {"#", "origen", "destino", "duracion", "precio"};
     //se crea la Tabla
     table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
     //table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
     //Creamos un JscrollPane y le agregamos la JTable
     JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
     add(scrollPane);
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48589/discussion-on-answer-by-sioesi-llenar-table-con-mis-datos-recibidos-en-eclipse-w).